crumbly fudge, separated fats. What can I do better?
I was making American Test Kitchen's Chocolate Fudge recipe it is behind a pay wall so here is the youtube video of them making it here. It is the same recipe.
The results are got were very crumbly and not very fudge like. More like a chocolate bar. I would like to know how I can make fudge better next time. I do not have experience working with chocolate and new to making candy.
From what I can tell the fat separated from the chocolate I would like guidance on how to prevent this.
Below are the overall steps from the recipe what I hypothesis was the problem was in step 2 perhaps the sugar was too hot or my dutch oven retained too much heat? Or in step 3 I could have whisked harder. Can I use my standmixer for whisking?
Summarized the steps are the following:

Heat sugar, butter, evaporated milk to 234 F

Take off heat, add chocolate and marshmallows. I used 80% cacao bitter sweet.

Whisk everything till looks like frosting

Stur in nuts

Put in  baking dish to cool for 2 hours, then put in the fridge for 2 hours.

Cut and serve.


Below are images of the final product.
 


It does, it is the same recipe. I edited to clarify.

The extra 4 degrees isn't helping, certainly. Candy is particular about temperatures. I also wonder if this is a rough cast-iron Dutch oven, or is it one with a smooth porcelain lining? Anything that gets the sugar crystalizing early (which a rough pot interior can encourage - but so do loose sugar crystals not washed off the walls of the pot into the mass to melt) will be detrimental to fudge.

Does the recipe specify what kind of chocolate to use? 80% is relatively high for a dark chocolate. If the recipe says dark chocolate you should be fine but if it is meant for milk chocolate that difference might be a problem.

This is almost certainly the result of not using a sugar/candy thermometer or measuring the stage of the sugar cooking. If you don't get the temperature right, the candy won't form properly. I'd suspect that you overcooked the sugar and it "cracked", meaning that it formed a solid lump that excluded the fat because it was too hot. The times in the recipe (and many recipes) are indicative only, not to be taken as gospel, as the temperatures reached in the given time-frame are dependent on stove element output, pot area and ingredient volume.
Without a sugar thermometer need to test the status of the sugar to ensure that it has reached the right temperature is to measure the texture of the sugar by dropping droplets into ice cold water and feeling the resulting ball. This is moderately subjective and takes some practice to get right. For fudge you want the "soft ball" stage.

I checked with an instant read thermometer for 238 Is that too hot? (I see in recipe that 234 is the right temperature so I agree with the possibility). It did also seem sudden when all the fat left the chocolate when I was whisking it.
